# How to connect to SQL Server 2012 from vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I've looked through the Web for the better part of 2 days trying to find how to connect to SQL Server 2012 that came with VS Express 2013 for Desktop.

Based on some things I found on various sites, in my connection string (starting with "") I've tried

```
Server=.\MSSQLEXPRESS;Database=BrightStar;user=root;password=root
```

then

```
.(local)\MSSQLEXPRESS
```

and

```
.(localhost)\MSSQLEXPRESS)
```

as well as all combinations without the "MS" (just `SQLEXPRESS`).

Nothing works so far.

The error message is

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

So the question is, what is the instance name of the SQL Server that comes packaged with this version of Visual Studio? Also, I haven't gotten to the "user" and "password" parameters, but help would be welcome there, too. (I was guessing at "root".)

If there's any other information I can provide that would be helpful, please ask.

Thanks.

(BTW, is this SQL Anywhere?)

Comment: Check out [ConnectionString.com](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.connectionstrings.com%2F&ei=0jE0VNS8CIeiyQSEm4HIAg&usg=AFQjCNFp35VmkJSg5VOClxRITQ5sJhjCbQ&sig2=goz6SK6O7DBlKTksPB5sFw&bvm=bv.76943099,d.aWw)

Comment: can you login to Your SSMS

Comment: First thing is to check SQL Server Configuration Manager - verify the instance name that is installed and that the service is running.

Comment: I don't think VS Express 2013 comes with that edition of SQL Server, just the LocalDB version, so you have to install it yourself. I suggest getting the version with management studio ("with Tools"). Scott Hanselman has done the hard work of finding out where the actual download links are: [Download SQL Server Express](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSQLServerExpress.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a normal installation without changes, then you have **SQL Server Express** with an instance name of `SQLEXPRESS`.

So you can connect to that either using

```
.\SQLEXPRESS
```

or

```
(local)\SQLEXPRESS
```

or

```
your-machine-name\SQLEXPRESS
```

(or even with your IP, if you want to)

The `.` or `(local)` (or `localhost`, if you insist) stand for the **local machine** and the `\SQLEXPRESS` is the default instance name for a SQL Server Express installation.

With SQL Server **2012** and newer, you also get the **LocalDB** feature - [learn more about LocalDB here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx)

To connect to that instance, you'd use

```
(LocalDB)\v11.0
```

as the server/instance name (or `(LocalDB)\v12.0` for SQL Server 2014 LocalDB)

For a great intro to SQL Server 2012 LocalDB, see Aaron Bertrand's article [Getting Started with SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/)

Comment: Oops sorry, I only caught one typo